# Unresolved Reference and I have no idea why

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I am completely lost, this made be just me being stupid but I have no idea what to do.
For some reason the topn is an unresolved reference.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKtNs.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB4T8.png

The code is:

```
topn = ""
print(topn)

def addApp():
    topn = topn + "1"
```

Comment: try saying `topn = ''` inside the function too

Comment: what do you mean?, could you please clarify

Comment: Just add `global topn` to the top of your function

Comment: OMG, you are my saviour, this might have been very obvious but this is a lifessaver.